# SQL Query to find unique count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's a little bit of background.  I have a database like this:

```
    uristem       username
  +------------+  +-------+
  | /uristem/1 |  | user1 |
  | /uristem/2 |  | user2 |
  | /uristem/3 |  | user3 |
  | /uristem/3 |  | user4 |
  | /uristem/1 |  | user1 |
  | /uristem/7 |  | user5 |
  | /uristem/5 |  | user3 |
  | /uristem/5 |  | user1 |
  | /uristem/3 |  | user1 |
  +------------+  +-------+
```

I need to count the number of (**unique**) users that hit `/uristem/3`.  What operators can I use in a query to do this?

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'm not skilled in this area and know very little, so it helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username)
FROM yourTableName
WHERE uristem = '/uristem/3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is one table with 2 columns.

```
Select Count(Distinct username)
From Table
Where uristem = '/uristem/3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the number of unique unsers that hit `/uristem/3`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS nb
FROM `your_table`
WHERE `uristem`='/uristem/3'
```